# Is it possible to provide access to the smart contract only from the application and block direct access?

Tags: ethereum, solidity, smartcontracts

For example, I have a game, and I want the players to interact, only through the application. But they can call functions if they just copy the ABI and contact address.

Is there any case to allow call public contract functions only through the application, using some kind of secret token? But I don’t know how to make such a secret token in the public blockchain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) One way to handle this is to sign the transactions yourself instead of having the user do it. You can add a modifier to the function like `onlyAdmin` and designate your app's account address as the admin. Then those functions will revert if called by anyone else.

The problem with this is you will have to pay gas and have mechanisms in your game to ensure that users can not exploit usage of your signing key.

```
function doSomething(bytes32 userId) public onlyAdmin {
  // ...
}
```

(2)
The other thing you can do is set a value that gets hashed in the function, then verify that hash. In the game you can give the user the value that will pass verification, downside is you will have to make sure to update the hash after each use.

To do this you can emit an Event and listen for it then send a tx to update the `appHash`, but this costs you gas and may expose you to a timing attack depending on what the rest of your implementation is like.

You could also set the function to a locked state which you then unlock by resetting the appHash, but again this requires work and gas on your end.

```
bytes32 public appHash = '1s2a3d4g';

function doSomething(appSecret bytes32) public {
  require(keccak256(appSecret) == appHash);
  // ...
  emit didSomething(msg.sender, appSecret);
}
```

With lock

```
bytes32 public appHash = '1s2a3d4g';
bool public locked = false;

function doSomething(bytes32 appSecret) public {
  require(keccak256(appSecret) == appHash);
  require(locked == false);
  // ...
  locked = true;
}

function unlock(bytes32 nextAppHash) public onlyAdmin {
  appHash = nextAppHash;
  locked = false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If secret token related logic is included in contract, that can be visible to anyone who runs node, so it seems to be difficult.

Normal web server can use cookie and domain name checking etc to protect api, but smart contract cannot access data outside contract, and data inside contracts are visible, so password protection is difficult.

Only possible solution seems using cryptographic digital signature, and use proxy server.
Proxy server control request from application, and create signed request to smart contract which permits request only from proxy server.